# How to scroll or move the container in LWUIT-1.5?

Tags: java-me, containers, lwuit

How to scroll the container without using default method called

```
setScrollable(true),
setScrollableX(true), 
setScrollableY(true).
```

Here my code,

```
btnLeft = new Button(imgLeft);      

btnRight = new Button(imgRight);

Container menuContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

 String[] menuArray = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX"};
 for (index = 0; index < menuArray.length; index++) {
            btnMenu = new Button((String) locale.get(menuArray[index]));
 menuContainer.addComponent(btnMenu);
        }

 menuContainer.setScrollableX(true);
```

It should move to right & left while clicking right & left button.

Can any one say is it possible in this LWUIT-1.5?

Answer (score 1):

It will be helpful if you can tell us how you want to build your interface. 
So, I have tried it with setScrollabeX and it works, but I'm navigating using the focus. If you want to click the `Button` and make the scroll, you should put in the functionality of the `Button` something like this:

In the action of the `Button` Right, you must set the focus to the `Button` in the right side of the `Container` and vice versa. Use  the `Form` method setFocused(put the Component here) or using the `Button` method requestFocus()